# Display a control in both orientations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

I've got a button designed on Portrait Orientattion, when I switch to Landscape it doesn't appear, what should I do so that it stays all the time?

Comment: If you support both landscape & portrait, you should design 2 layouts for both orientations.

Comment: I know, but I've got Split-View application

Comment: so you are working on an iPad project. After rotation, the IB items should always in the scene, but just rotated out of the screen. Consider rotating the screen elements & apply transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the proper [AutoresizingMasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAutoresizing) for your UIViews. For example, it might be that your button has a y-coordinate that is larger than the device's width and has a fixed top resizing mask, so if you turn the device to landscape mode it gets clipped. Doing this...

```
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

...will cause the button to shrink its top margin, moving on screen.

In your comment you mentioned that this is a split-view app, if your button is in the root view controller of the split view, you should probably add support for restoring the root view controller as a popover.